# wifi problem in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, wireless

I am unable to connect to wifi.

I am not getting BROADBAND BCM in additional drivers.

When I run `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` I get the following error:

```
 08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
DeviceName: Realtek RTL8723BE 802.11b/g/n 1x1Wi-Fi + BT4.0 Combo Adapter
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
Kernel modules: rtl8723be, wl
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: And also you installed a wrong driver `wl`. It is not "Broadband" it is "Broadcom". "Broadcom" is a vendor name of wireless chips. You do not need it. And you can remove it by `sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source`.